# MVC - Unity with HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I would like to inject my configuration service in the HTTP handler. I would not like to use `DependencyResolver`. Is there any possibility to inject my service in the constructor?

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private readonly IConfigurationService _configurationService;

    public MyHandler()
    {
        //TODO: servicelocator is anti-pattern imo, how to do constructor injection in IHttpHandler??
        _configurationService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IConfigurationService)) as IConfigurationService;
    }

    public MyHandler(IConfigurationService configurationService)
    {
        //TODO: I would like to use this constructor
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [IHttpHandlerFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227439.aspx). You can create your handler inside the factory. You need to register the factory with IIS in web.config. Therefore, the factory becomes a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) for handlers.

Comment: So I have to use DependencyResolver in factory...? Or you mean something else?

Comment: The factory will become a new composition root and therefore you would create the dependencies directly inside it. Either via creating a container, registering the mappings, and then resolving the handler, or by using [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).